# How can i deserialize and serialize complex json data bu Newton json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

i made a jquery filter tool which returns to my server side filter data as json. i wanna convert it a C# class and also i want to convert any C# class to my json.

My json and it's mirror C# class below :

```
[{"field":{"label":"Category","value":"category"},"operator":{"label":"any of","value":"in"},"value":{"label":"(Family, Friends)","value":"1,2"}},{"field":{"label":"Age","value":"age"},"operator":{"label":">","value":"gt"},"value":{"label":"18","value":"18"}},{"field":{"label":"Firstname","value":"firstname"},"operator":{"label":"equals","value":"eq"},"value":{"label":"\"test\"","value":"test"}},{"field":{"label":"Lastname","value":"lastname"},"operator":{"label":"equals","value":"eq"},"value":{"label":"\"test2\"","value":"test2"}}]
```

C# mirror:

```
public class Field
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Operator
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Field field { get; set; }
    public Operator @operator { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}
```

i tried this way :

```
   public class ViewFilter
{
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
    public List<RootObject> RootObjects { get; set; }
}
    public class Field
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Operator
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Field field { get; set; }
        public Operator @operator { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }
```

i tried :

```
 var result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModel.ViewFilter>>(filter).ToList();


       foreach (ViewModel.ViewFilter item in result)
       {


       }
```

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_serializeobject.htm

Comment: @avi Turner ; i rearranged my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When receiving the data, use the NewtonSoft JsonConvert class:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(yourString, serializerSettings);
```

The **yourString** value being the string your are getting which contains your json data.

The [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_camelcasepropertynamescontractresolver.htm) takes care of serializing objects names in camel case as its name indicates.

Comment: Your json content is the mirror of what you have as a `List<RootObject>`. What you tried is to serialize against your `ViewFilter` class, which is not a `List<RootObject>`, but contains it. Try my statement.